# Android: EditText long press menu

Tags: android, sense

what is [this thing](http://i335.photobucket.com/albums/m470/jmartin866/actionbarlol.png) and how do i add to it?

it's not the normal selection popup.  is this native to Android or part of the Sense UI?

HTC Thunderbolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a Quick Action Dialog, it's custom, you can see an example of how you can make one [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).